Is this design approach for a DC motor H-Bridge correct?
I am designing an H-bridge circuit to drive two linear actuators. The circuit also has low noise differential ADCs that will be measuring strain gauges. I want to isolate the ADCs as much as I can from the motor noise.

Is this design approach I have come up with in the right direction?
Would there be any benefit from having two linear regulators?



Probably nothing. Please post your schematic if you have one.

I don't have a schematic, first trying to decide on the design first

Consider no isolation and just a regulator for your MCU and surrounding components.

Why no isolation? that would cause a lot of noise

Noise = bad layout mostly, but if you really do need it, isolate your ADC path. Plenty of digital isolators for the very purpose available. Cheaper and more effective than to isolate your motor + drive.
